git range-diff uses ... but nushell thinks they are cell paths
I have this nushell function:
def rebase-diff [oldtip:string,newtip:string] {
    git range-diff $oldtip...$newtip | save -f rebase-diff.txt | start ./rebase-diff.txt
}

When I run it I get:
 × Data cannot be accessed with a cell path
     ╭─[C:\Users\Yathindu.Hettiarachc\AppData\Roaming\nushell\config.nu:869:1]
 869 │ def rebase-diff [oldtip:string,newtip:string] {
 870 │     git range-diff $oldtip...$newtip | save -f rebase-diff.txt | start ./rebase-diff.txt
     ·                            ┬
     ·                            ╰── string doesn't support cell paths
 871 │ }
     ╰────


So nushell thinks I'm using . but I just want it to just use ... literally.
Is there a way to escape .?

Try String Interpolation: git range-diff $"($oldtip)...($newtip)" | …

A string value, when used literally, generally requires quoting. However, Nu allows dropping the quotes if it only contains "word characters" and is not used in a command position. These are called bare strings.
The dot . is not a word character, so some sort of quoting is necessary. To combine it with the values of the variables, you could use

string concatenation with +:
git range-diff ($oldtip + '...' + $newtip) | …


string interpolation with $:
git range-diff $'($oldtip)...($newtip)' | …



